Serve SPA (Angular) from Cloudflare R2
I am trying to serve my SPA (Angular) from R2.
However, the website doesn’t load and I get a 404 error for /login.
Would appreciate any help on this.
My index.html loads after I added the transform rule as described in the post: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/index-html-as-root-object-for-spa/581177/3
I was successfully able to setup using Cloudflare and API Gateway with OCI Object Storage.
I had setup deployment rules as show in the post: https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/oci-api-gateway-web-hosting/index.html#task-7-test
Do I need to specify similar setting for serving *.js & *.css files? If yes, how?
